# how to send array data to one component to other in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have one component called cards.js which holds Json data,
I also have an independent component called tabledata.js, I just want to pass the array data to this tabledata.js component from card.js when user click on the card.
How can I d that please I need help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnUN7.png)

here is the project folder structure.

Here is the Cards.js Code
Here I am trying to send Data object to TableData.js

```
{Data.map((items) => {
          return (
            <>
                <TableData row={items}/>
              <Card
                className={classes.root}
                onClick={() => {
                 
                }}
              >
```

Here is TableData.js Code

```
function TableData({row}) {
const classes = useStyles();

const [rows, setRows] = useState(row);

{rows.map((e)=>{
console.log(e);
 })}
```

Comment: can you add some code ?

Comment: Here is the Code

Answer (score 0):

tell me if that work :

```
        {Data.map((items) => {
                  return (
                      <Card
                        className={classes.root}
                        onClick={() => {
                         <TableData row={items}/>
                        }}
                      />
                        )
              }
```

Comment: it says it is undefined while receiving it in tableData.js as a props